# SAS Programming - removing duplicates

Tags: sas, radix, sas-macro

I have the following data based on distance between the cities.

```
Source Destination Distance 
USA       UK        1000 
USA      Spain      200 
UK        USA       1000 
Germany  Spain      500 
Spain     USA       200
```

I want to remove the duplicates where source and destination are same. For Example **USA** to **UK** will be same as **UK** to **USA** and hence the duplicate value needs to be removed.

Following is the desired output.

```
Source Destination Distance 
USA        UK        1000 
USA      Spain       200 
Germany  Spain       500
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and explain what the problem is with the output you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First produce a dummy variable to hold sorted source and destination by call sortc, then sort by dummy variable.

```
data have;
input Source $ Destination $ Distance;
cards;
USA       UK        1000 
USA      Spain      200 
UK        USA       1000 
Germany  Spain      500 
Spain     USA       200 
;

data temp;
    set have;
    length dummy $50.;
    _var1=source; _var2=destination;
    call sortc (of _:);
    dummy=catx(' ',of _:);
    drop _:;
run;

proc sort data=temp out=want(drop=dummy) nodupkey;
by dummy;
run;
```

Comment: simple and very effective solution

Comment: Thankyou for the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a Dimension / lookup table for all the routes you want, then lookup the values to standardise the output you want.

I created a lookup table called Routes, and  variable containing all the pair values to lookup.

Full Code:

```
data have;
input Source $ Destination $ Distance ;
datalines;
USA       UK        1000
USA      Spain      200
UK        USA       1000
Germany  Spain      500
Spain     USA       200
;
run;
data routes;
infile datalines dsd dlm=',';
length pairs $50.;
input Source $ Destination $ Distance Pairs $ ;
datalines;
USA,UK,1000,USA-UK/UK-USA
USA,Spain,200,USA-Spain/Spain-USA
Germany, Spain,500,Germany-Spain/Spain-Germany
;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
     Select distinct 
     t2.Source, t2.Destination,  t2.Distance
     from have  t1 inner join routes t2 on
      t2.Pairs contains catx('-',t1.Source,t1.Destination) or 
      t2.Pairs contains catx('-',t1.Destination,t1.Source)
;
quit;
```

Output:

```
 Source=Germany Destination=Spain Distance=500 
 Source=USA Destination=Spain Distance=200 
 Source=USA Destination=UK Distance=1000
```